# Strange issue after removing bug

Tags: debugging

I removed a bug in my LaTeX code. Now the section is bug free because it uses code from a Lamport book. But it still is included in the pdf after using `pdflatex` more than once. 
What is the problem? Can somebody give me a hint for debugging?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your prob occured -in my case- firstly in 2004. by coincidence it was solved when removing temporary files, extension `aux`. (btw i gave this hint another person in 2012 and it solved also his issue) it's a time waster.

therefore as far as i read:
for instance, within apple terminal (rm .. remove):

```
    rm *.aux
    pdflatex doc.tex
    bibtex doc
    pdflatex doc.tex
    pdflatex doc.tex
```

concerning debugging, take sometimes a break. 
i prefer an apple texteditor with an adequate font size. at the begin of using latex, avoid the `-sloppy` parameter when compiling and read carefully the error messages. That's half the battle. :-) at the start, use google for these error messages. after a while, you will laugh about many early errors. for instance, if you forget the math environment, then an error message clearly points to the missing `$` sign.